# MySQL Connector throw exception Only TimeSpan objects can be serialized by MySqlTimeSpan when I use TimeSpan

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, c#-4.0, timespan

As I read, I have problem with MySql Connector. I use MySql and NHibernate.

I've class which includes this field:

```
private TimeSpan begin;
private TimeSpan end;
```

The fields are mapped by this:

```
<property name="Begin" column="start" type="TimeAsTimeSpan" />
<property name="End" column="koniec" type="TimeAsTimeSpan" />
```

Exception is caused by this (line hourDAO.save(hour)):

```
TimeSpan begin = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0);
TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(7, 45, 0);
HourDAO hourDAO = new HourDAO();
Hour hour = new Hour();
hour.Begin = begin;
hour.End = end;
hourDAO.save(hour);
```

Why it is? Can you explain me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your types in mapping from `TimeAsTimeSpan` to `TimeSpan`

```
<property name="Begin" column="start" type="TimeSpan" />
<property name="End" column="koniec" type="TimeSpan" />
```